# The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started, EXIT error code 0

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I wanted to upgrade MySQL from 5.7.24 to 8.0.20, so I followed the steps [here](https://www.nairaland.com/1565023/how-successfully-upgrade-mysql-wamp).

TL;DR, I downloaded and extracted the MySQL 8 zip file in *C:/Wamp/bin/mysql*, and copied the old *data* folder, *my.ini*, and *wampserver.conf* into the new *mysql8.0.20* folder.
I also changed all instances of '5.7.24' to '8.0.20' in *my.ini*, and ran the command `mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure`.

This is my *my.ini* file without comments:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[wampmysqld64]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M

table_definition_cache = 600

sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
basedir="C:/Wamp/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.20"
log-error="C:/Wamp/logs/mysql.log"
log_error_verbosity=2
datadir="C:/Wamp/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.20/data"

lc-messages-dir="C:/Wamp/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.20/share"
lc-messages=en_US

default-storage-engine=MYISAM

secure_file_priv="C:/Wamp/tmp"
skip-ssl

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true

sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

skip-federated

server-id = 1

skip-slave-start

early-plugin-load=""

innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method=normal

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port = 3306
```

But when I run Wamp, the icon stays orange and it says only 2 of 3 services are running. If I check the state of services, it says:

```
The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started
EXIT error code:0
Help message for error code 0 is: The operation completed successfully.
```

Which means everything works correctly. And it does. I can use MySQL and open the console without any problem. So why is the icon still orange?

If I go in services.msc and look for *wampmysqld64*, the service is not running, and I cannot start it:

```
The wampmysqld64 service on Local Computer started and then stopped.
Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
```

I also deleted the files *ib_logfile0*, *ib_logfile1*, and *ibdata1* from the *mysql8.0.20/data* folder.

If I go back to the old MySQL version, the error still persists.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting this issue after installing a WAMP upgrade

Comment: Sorry Mike, I have no idea how I solved this then, it's been 3 years. Since I haven't replied with the solution then, I assume it was not a convenient one - such as a complete reinstall or something.
But I remember that I had a similar problem another time and @Potatodragon's answer was the solution - I had a MySQL instance running on Docker as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a high probability that you are using another service such as workbench or something else that uses the mySQL server. From what I read in the forum for Wamp and my limited understanding of what is happening. The other service uses the port 3306. I shifted my port to 3308 and my service automatically started running. If you have the same problem as me, you can just change the port number. For other more detailed problems you can refer to the forum attached below.
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,152310,152476

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed the Visual C++ Packages , its in the Information panel when installing WAMP.

--- Visual C++ Packages ---

The MSVC runtime libraries VC9, VC10, VC11 are required for Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions with VC11. Runtimes VC13, VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17 or more

- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)

The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

- VC13 Packages Update 5(Visual C++ 2013)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032938/
- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015 Update 3) Supersedes by VC15
- VC15 Redistribuable (Visual C++ 2017)Supersedes by VC16
- VC16 Redistribuable (Visual C++ 2015-2019)

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

I personally was missing the last one

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  I recently started learning SQL using MySQL and the recommended tool was installing "MySQL Workbench".  Great tool! MySQL Workbench does in fact share the same port as 3306 as MySQL used in WAMP. Thanks for the 5-sec fix.  right click WAMP icon => Tools, go to section "Port used by MySQL: 3306" and select "Use a port other than 3306", watch the Wamp Server icon go "GREEN"

Thanks for the fix!